# Printing message in specific place on screen with DOS int 21h in graphic mode

Tags: assembly, text, printing, dos, x86-16

I want to print out strings in assembly, I've managed to print out a string but I can't figure out how to print it in a specific place on the screen

This is the code I'm using:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

message db 'Hello World',10,13,'$'

CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

       ;graphic mode:;
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h

    pop ds
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

The graphic mode is because this is part of a bigger project I'm working on but to my understanding it shouldn't be a problem.

This program does print out the message it just prints it out on the upper right corner of my screen.
I would very much like to know how to print the message in a specific place and also determine its size if possible.

Comment: At the graphics level you probably have to use the screen buffer directly.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to position the cursor where you need the string to appear.
The screen 13h has 40 columns and 25 rows.
Use BIOS function 02h:

```
mov dl, 20    ;Center column
mov dh, 12    ;Center row
mov bh, 0     ;Display page 0
mov ah, 02h   ;SetCursor
int 10h
mov dx, offset message
mov ah, 09h   ;DispayString
int 21h
```

---

> ```
> pop ds
> ```

What's this doing in your code?

---

> ...also determine its size if possible.

Write the following:

```
message db 'Hello World',10,13,'$'
size    equ ($-1)-message
```

**$** is the position where the current line (code) starts.
Here *size* will get 13 bytes.

Then use it like:

```
mov cx, size
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use BIOS functions for string output as well?   [AH=9 / int 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09) writes to STDOUT, which could have been redirected to a file.  Or is it normal for DOS programs that do cursor-movement to assume that their output wasn't redirected?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think that for a project where the user selects a specific graphics mode, it's a safe assumption that they don't expect any redirection to happen. Using BIOS output functions then is just a matter of taste.